How to properly clear terminal styling attributes
I'm writing a cross-platform library for Delphi in Pascal for writing & reading from the terminal.
I use a combination of functions from the Winapi.Windows unit and some Linux control characters to change the background and foreground colors of the text which is being echoed on the screen.
I'm experiencing a issue where the background color of the previous line is somehow overflowing onto the next line, but not overflowing on itself.
Image

Here is some code which outputs this exact result
for var I := 1 to 6  do
  begin
    var TextAttrib: integer;
    var Buff: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
    const Handle = TTextRec(Output).Handle;

    // Red
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Buff);
    TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
    TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(4) shl 4);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

    System.WriteLn('Debug test');
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);

    // Green
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Buff);
    TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
    TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(2) shl 4);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

    System.WriteLn('Color filler test');
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);

    // Blue
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Buff);
    TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
    TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(1) shl 4);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

    System.WriteLn('Line overflow');
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);
    System.WriteLn('');
  end;

On Windows, the issue only occurs after the 4th or so echo, but the Linux equivalent of this code always has this same issue. In any case, there is clearly an issue with my method.
So, what am I doing wrong?

Why are you calling SetConsoleTextAttribute() twice before WriteLn() for the 2nd-4th lines? Do you have the same problem if you use SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() instead of SetConsoleTextAttribute()?

@RemyLebeau I call SetConsoleTextAttribute() with the $0F attribute value in an attempt to "reset" the style to the default, which is $0F. This kind of works for the last line, but does not seem to have any effect otherwise. As for SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(), It does not seem to fix the issue. Also, It could not be the cause of the problem, since the Linux version of the code has the exact same issue, and It uses different functions.

I'm not familiar with Windows or Delphi, this comment is for the Linux part. Most terminal emulators have a terrible misfeature called "background color erase". When you've reached the bottom and a new line scrolls in, it receives the currently active background color, yikes! A partial workaround is to restore the default attributes before printing the newline character. This won't save you when a longer line automatically wraps to the next line due to overflow, but that's for another day. I'm planning to write a detailed doc about the situation, I'll link to it when it's done.

@egmont I think you're right! I noticed this behavior that the problem only occurred after the terminal scrolls down a bit. It happens both on windows and on Linux. I didn't add this in my question since I believed It to be just a visual bug. Thank you for this information and please link your document when It's done.

@egmont What you call "misfeature " when text attributes seems to transfer to the new line is actually by design. You see text attributes are not limited to specific lines but in fact affects all the text that is written after they have been set until the point when they are changed again. This can be in a same line or after multiple lines. Check additional example that I have included in my answer of how to apply multiple different background colours in a same line that is possible by the way of how text attribues work.

@SilverWarior Yes I know it's by design; a conceptually horribly broken design. Simple utilities like ls or grep cannot just print a fragment of text in a different background color and have it appear as common sense would dictate, and there's not even a known and reliable workaround for that. See bugzilla.gnome.org/754596 and debbugs.gnu.org/15444 for a start (also this very post here). Whatever the design goal was, it should have been designed in a way that doesn't unfixably break the behavior of the simplest utilities out there that just want to print a piece of colored text.

@egmont You can change text attributes for existing console text using WriteConsoleOutputAttribute. It does however needs you to know exact location of the text whose appearance you want to change..

Again, I'm not familiar with Windows, I'm talking about Linux. Querying the location of the text (cursor) is cumbersome enough that it's unreasonable for apps to go into that depth (they just want to simply printf() stuff), is subject to race condition if the user just resizes the window, and isn't possible if there's no terminal underneath but you still want colors (e.g. piping to less -R). If simple utilities can't simply just printf() and expect it to work correctly, if they need to resort to complicated, fragile, platform-specific workarounds then it's a bug in the platform's design.

When I try your code in a simple Delphi console application I get no coloured background at all.
When debugging I see that value for Handle is 0. And that is different of what GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) returns.
So when your code is calling SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib); it is actually trying to set text atributes to wrong handle.

In light of that I have modified your code so that it properly retrieves console handle right from the start
var Handle: THandle;
Handle := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

for var I := 0 to 10 do
begin
  var TextAttrib: integer;
  var Buff: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;

  System.WriteLn('');
  // Red
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(4) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

  System.WriteLn('Debug test');
  //SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);

  // Green
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(2) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

  System.WriteLn('Color filler test');
  //SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);

  // Blue
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(1) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);

  System.WriteLn('Line overflow');
  //SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);

  // Multicolored line
  // Red text part
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(4) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);
  Write('Red text');
  // Space without background
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);
  Write(' ');
  // Green text part
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(2) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);
  Write('Green text');
  // Space without background
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);
  Write(' ');
  // Blue text part
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(1) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);
  Write('Blue text');
  // Space without background
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, $0F);
  Write(' ');

  // Red background colour for entire line
  // We need to write string whose size matches the console line size
  // which we can retrieve from TConsoleScreenBufferInfo by reading 
  // dwSize.X field
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(Handle, Buff);
  TextAttrib := Buff.wAttributes and $FF0F;
  TextAttrib := TextAttrib or (Word(4) shl 4);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(Handle, TextAttrib);
  System.WriteLn('');
  var S: String;
  S := 'Red background for entire line';
  SetLength(S, Buff.dwSize.X);
  System.WriteLn(S);

  System.WriteLn('');
end;

ReadLn;

Also I have added two more examples for of changing background colour.
First one displays of how you can get multiple different background colours in a single line. It makes use of Write instead of WiteLn in order to write individual parts of a single line. This is possible since SetConsoleTextAttribute affects all text that is written afterwards.
Second one displays of how you can get coloured background for entire line. In order to do this you need to write string whose size matches the size of console line.
Do note that on Windows resizing console window causes text attributes of the last printable character in a line to be applied to the end of the line.
I'm not sure if this code will work the same on Linux  as it does in Windows since I haven't tested it out.

PS: If you want to split your text into multiple lines you can use Write and add new line character into proper location within your string like this:
Write('First line'+sLineBreak+'Second line');

sLineBreak is defined in system unit in a way so that proper platform specific new line character is used.

I tried your code, but unfortunately the issue still occurred. It only occurs after the console scrolls down. Maybe you had your console windows maximised and that's why the issue didn't occur, since It never scrolled down. In an comment, @egmont explained that the properties of a line gets inherited downwards.
But, I tried using sLineBreak as you suggested and "clearing" the line by using Write() on the text, than clearing the attributes to $0F and then using Write(sLineBreak), and what do you know, that seems to do the trick!

@Codrut During my testings I even tried loop with 1000 iteration so the console window did scroll quite a bit but still haven't experienced any problems. When your console window is first shown is its scrollbar already visible? If not then showing it later would cause reduction in console client area and thus size of individual lines. That might then lead to similar problem as I mentioned in my answer about resizing console window.  try reading the line size using Buff.dwSize.X before and after the problem occurs to see if it changes.
